# How does the 'Site Stats' work on Lifehacks SE?

Tags: discussion, statistics

How does the site stats work on Lifehacks SE?

[image: Stats displayed on Lifehacks SE page]

In the above image, stats say there are 1208 questions and 4268 answers.

Do they represent the total number of questions asked in Lifehacks SE till date or is there any other way of calculation ?

Also, how is that '100%' answered percentage arrived at ?

Comment: Could you elaborate?

Comment: I have elaborated my question. Please see the edit . @Arazio

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1208 is the total number of questions asked and 4268 is the number of answers among them.

100% answered means that of the 1208 questions, 100% have at least one answer posted to them.